# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioredis'

Tags: python, redis

After installing aioredis it's showing error with module not found. I have instedd aioredis with **pip install aioredis**  still I'm facing this error.

```
$ pip install aioredis
Requirement already satisfied: aioredis in /home/super/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout in /home/super/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aioredis) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/super/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aioredis) (4.1.1)
```

This is my line number 3

```
import aioredis
```

Output:

> line 3, in 
> import aioredis ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioredis'

Comment: Are you sure installed your module for the same Python interpreter version as you are using to run?

Comment: yes, I have installed for both pyenv versions, Glolbal and 3.9.5

Comment: What does it say when you do `print(sys.version)`? ofc with import first

Comment: 3.9.5 (default, Mar 23 2022, 10:54:03)

[GCC 9.4.0]

Comment: Okay, then one more check, what environment are you using - Jupyter notebook, running a script, REPL?

Comment: I'm using the python with linux, with pyenv 3.9.5 on VS Code

Comment: Out of ideas then, but I think there is something wrong with your setup as I just tried installing it for myself and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I have already use previously, It was new setup for freshOS

Comment: Did you found the issue? I'm having the exact same problem. This is odd because all other installed packages seems to work just fine. The issue is with aioredis for me too.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. Try to use pipenv as a development environment.

1. Install pipenv via pip

   `pip3 install --user pipenv`
2. Install packages you need

   `pipenv install aioredis`
3. Run pipenv shell

   `pipenv shell`
4. Run your server

   `pipenv run python3 manage.py runserver`